# PE FILE reading in c

Tags: c, portable-executable

I need to check if file is PE file or not. I need to check first two byte is MZ or not and I did this.

This is my task: When verifying the PE format, not only according to the MZ expression, but also using the conditions that the IMAGE_NT_HEADERS structure is read and the Signature field is verified by reading the IMAGE_FILE_HEADER field and the Machine field is equal to the Th value IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386 or IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64.

I cannot figure how can do the rest of them. I hope you can help me.

```
int checkPE(char *file){
    int fd=open(file,READ_FLAGS,0777);
    char buffer[TWOBYTE+1] = {'\0'};
    size_t bytes_read;
    char ch;

    if(fd==-1){ //if file cannot be opened give a error message.
        perror("The file cannot be opened.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    bytes_read = read(fd,buffer,TWOBYTE); 
    if(bytes_read==-1){ 
        perror("Error while reading file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(strcmp(buffer,MZ)!=0){
        return -1;
    }
  
    int closeFlag = close(fd); 
    if(closeFlag==-1){ 
        perror("The file cannot be closed.\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than `perror("The file cannot be opened.\n");`, you will get a much friendlier error message with `perror(file);`. I have never encountered a message like `The file cannot be opened.` that was not immediately followed by swearing and exasperated shouts of `which file?!?!?`

Comment: @WilliamPursell ahaha okay I will fix this later.

Comment: When you read data out of a binary file using `read`, you are almost always dealing with *counted arrays of `char`*, **not** null-terminated strings.  So to read and check that the first two bytes are `MZ`, you want `char buffer[2];`, and then `memcmp(buffer, MZ, 2)`.

Comment: The PE file format is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format). That's a pretty large chunk of text to digest. The number of options you'd have to check is immense, and I'm not aware of a full PE validation implementation in existence. If that is your task, you'll be busy for a *long* time. I doubt that is actually the problem you are trying to solve. You'll get better help if you explained what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing more than just parsing some structures. You have already the algorithm. I assume that you just need the implementation. Consider the following example utility.

***PS***: For further details, just comment it below.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <windows.h>
 
BOOL CheckValidity(BYTE* baseAddress);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("You didn't specified a PE file.\n");
        printf("Usage: CheckPEImage.exe <Full path of PE File>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return -1;
    HANDLE hMemoryMap = CreateFileMappingA(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (!hMemoryMap)
        return -2;
    PBYTE baseAddress = (PBYTE)MapViewOfFile(hMemoryMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
    if (!baseAddress)
        return -3;
    printf("PE Image is %s.\n", CheckValidity(baseAddress) ? "valid" : "invalid");
    getchar();
    return 0;
} 

BOOL CheckValidity(BYTE* baseAddress)
{
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER lpDosHeader;
    PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER lpFileHeader;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS lpNtHeaders;
    PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER lpOptionalHeader;
    lpDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)baseAddress;
    lpNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(baseAddress + lpDosHeader->e_lfanew); 
    if (lpDosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) 
        return FALSE;
    if (lpNtHeaders->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) 
        return FALSE;
    if (lpNtHeaders->FileHeader.Machine != IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386 && lpNtHeaders->FileHeader.Machine != IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64 && lpNtHeaders->FileHeader.Machine != IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand these code sorry. is ImageHlp.h 3. party library?

Comment: No, it is not. It is `Win32` API Library which contains some utility functions to parse `PE` Images and you don't need actually it. You don't have to understand it entirely. It is enough to understand the `CheckValidity` function.

Comment: Actually I do not understand. I did it like this here:: https://rioasmara.com/2021/10/16/c-code-parsing-pe-with-corkami-offset/

Comment: And I think it is okay.

Comment: I see.  `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER`, `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` and `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` are Microsoft-defined structures that defines the headers in `PE` image. It is much easier to work with these structures.

Comment: If you want to check the validity of `PE` images using the offsets, you can refer to the official [`PE Specification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format).

Comment: is there any source for contains and properties about windows.h library?

Comment: This is hardly an exhaustive validation. And it's written under the assumption that it will only be used with a valid PE image. The code certainly doesn't do much to protect against coincidental or malicious attacks (say, a file, where `e_lfanew` is negative). The code doesn't check whether the number of sections is as promised, nor does it even read any sections to check their integrity.

Comment: Sure, but I am not a Security Researcher. It is a simple validation from the perspective of a Software Developer. The details like yours must be mentioned by OP.